# Mapping backend JSON Array with 1 element: Object #<Object> has no method 'forEach'

Tags: ember.js

My JSON backend can return a single object or an array of objects.

My Ajax callback is managing the callback response.

It works fine if the response contains more than 1 object but an error is returned if the answer only contains a single object...

How to get a generic solution (1 or multiple objects) ?

```
function(response) {
  var posts=[];
  response.post.forEach( function (item) {
    posts.addObject( App.Post.create(item) );
  });
  return posts;
}
```

Comment: Can you check the length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out whether the object is an array or not by calling `Array.isArray()`.

Comment: Tx, it works but I was thinking there was a more "transparent" solution.

Comment: @fvisticot: The more "transparent" solution is to fix the server to return a consistent result.  Having an endpoint that only sometimes returns an array is a bad idea, as you're discovering.